# Laravel Check if any related records exist

Tags: laravel, view, relation

I have a Model `Category` and a Model `Subcategory`. These are related.

Now I want to check in a view if a category has subcategories. If so, run this code, if not run this code.

I thought of something like

```
 @forelse($categories as $category)
                            @if($category->subcategory)
                                <li class="sub-category">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/icon/'.$category->icon) }}" alt="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
                                        @foreach(isset($category->subcategory)) as $subcategory)
                                            <li class="sub-sec col-md-6">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#" class="title">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                                                    <!--//
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Single Item 1</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Single Item 2</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Single Item 3</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Single Item 4</a></li>
                                                    -->
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            @else
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/icon/'.$category->icon) }}" alt="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
                            @endif

                        @empty

                        @endforelse
```

But using `isset()` seems to be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this. Just use the count of subcategories to determine.

Example:

`if ($category->subcategory()->count() > 0)`

Maybe you should also change some names of variables, methods and relations. It makes reading much easier. For example you could rename your subcategory relations to subcategories since it will be more than one.

Your code would look something like:

```
@forelse ($categories as $category)

    <li>

        <a href="...">{{ $category->name }}</a>

        @if ($category->subcategory()->count() > 0) // Check if more than one subcategory

            @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory) // Change $category->subcategory to $category->subcategories

                ...

            @endforeach

        @endif

    </li>

@empty

    No categories

@endforelse
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This works like a charm. Regarding, using the plural form, I did that, just used the wrong names in the view lol. Thanks for pointing it out tho!

Comment: @Scarwolf Happy to help :)